# Is gold an acceptable means of currency exchange?

Tags: money, exchange, backpacking

To be honest, I am not sure which is a better way to ask the question: Is gold an acceptable means of currency exchange in most travel-able countries?  or which countries is gold NOT an acceptable means of currency exchange?

This question comes to mind in respect to backpacking across Eurasia.  I know most European countries take gold, but I have little knowledge on topic from Eastern Europe on to the eastern coast of China.

The idea is that gold carries a lot of value with very little displacement and weight.  With gold at it's current value, one could feasibly carry a few ounces to finance the trip.

Comment: Do you really plan to take gold with you? Why not Euros, Dollars and credit card?

Comment: I don't want to be tethered to a financial institution. I work at one and well aware of the problems that arrise when going to say, the Ukrane. There are countries that are "too high risk" to do any card transactions and are blocked all together. However, I would use combination of cash/gold. Cash can be bulky at the amount I want to carry, so I want to use gold as a backup.

Comment: So you think it is risky to use bank services in countries like the Ukraine. But on the other hand you don't think it is risky to backpack with a really heavy cluster of gold in your backpack for weeks through Eurasia?

Comment: As the question suggests, it would only be a few ounces, not really heavy clusters.

Comment: While gold is certainly a high-value commodity, its trade is regulated almost everywhere, mainly since it's a great way to illegally transfer wealth across borders, and is frequently used in money laundering schemes and tax evasion (it's hard to be traced, unlike electronic transactions, paper money or, to some extent, diamonds). Also, almost any amount of gold would cause raised eyebrows at customs, as you might be required to pay an import tax, and in certain countries, it might even be confiscated.

Comment: Why the downvotes people? This is perfectly legit question!

Comment: why? Because it's impossible to answer. Trading or even owning gold is and has been illegal or highly restricted in specific places and times, a list that's constantly changing (and you don't even mention where you are planning to do so).

Comment: Is this a serious question?! or are you trolling?

Comment: @jwenting Your comment posting is an answer in itself, which adds value to the question (though you chose not to make it an answer).  Don't be so quick to dismiss the qeustion as others were able to give answer I was looking for.

Comment: the question is too broad to give a globally relevant answer, hence no doubt the down votes (none of them mine btw). As you will note all the answers are specific to certain situations or locations, and for that very reason.

Comment: One word - Bitcoin.
http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

You can carry all your wealth "in your head", while just memorizing a simple pass phrase to access your funds. Of course, it's not wildly accepted as cash or gold, but you could always exchange it for "normal money" when you need.

Comment: How would you turn bitcoin into local currency? All the methods I've seen involve a bank account, which still leaves you the problem of getting the contents of that account into a local currency.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is certainly not true that "most European countries take gold". You cannot pay for goods in a shop with gold. Nor can you walk into a high street bank with gold and walk out with currency - you would need to do it through a specialist dealer.

There are places where you can sell gold jewellery, but you will get very poor prices.

Comment: Very helpful.  I guess I was mislead to thinking it was freely traded.

Answer (score 11):

Although gold is at a high value now, it's not easy to convert into cash. A lot of places are doing "cash for gold" in shops for people to sell their old jewlery etc. However they pay maybe one tenth the price per troy ounce. I know this is the case in numerous European countries. So you'll have to buy it at 100%, and sell it at 10%, meaning a 90% drop in value. Gold is a terrible way to convert your cash when travelling around Europe.

You'd be much better bringing Euro or US Dollars.

Answer (score 8):

I am not aware of any country where gold is an acceptable currency. Banks typically don't buy gold from strangers. They require that you have a checking account with them.

Jewellery stores, pawn shops and thelike will probably take your gold for cash, but it's a gamble: They'll guess the value and make an offer based on how much *they* value your coin. Maybe more importantly, you might not find such a shop when you need them.

The risk of a credit/debit card getting blocked is real. However, carrying two cards or one card and cash / traveller's cheques should be fairly save.

EURos are good all over Western and Central Europe. In Eastern Europe, Russia, and Asia, USD is popular. Changing cash is no longer the ripoff, it used to be; often cheaper than credit card transactions, certainly cheaper than selling gold.

Comment: Krugerrands are gold coins with no fixed fiat currency value which are legal tender. [Source](http://www.randrefinery.com/products_krugerrands.htm): *"It is important to note that although Krugerrands are considered legal tender, there is no record of their face value on either side of the coin. The rationale for this is that emphasis is laid on their direct link to the prevailing value of their fine gold content."*